# UILongPressGestureRecognizer location function issue in collectionView iOS 13.2

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, ios13, long-press, uilongpressgesturerecogni

I had this wired flashing with UILongPressGestureRecognizer location(in: UIView?) method when drag around item original position.

there is an unnatural flick when the cell.

[image]

it all works fine in iOS 12.

here is the link of demo project [demo](https://github.com/andrew54068/CustomGrid) fork from SumeetMourya

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue has been fix in iOS 13.6.